# Android WebView how to go to url

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

i have downloaded this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ project and now i want for each tab to load the url
 i have this code and instead of return new xxxFragment(); to do an webview go to url

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

i have an xml layout for each tab 
[image]

Comment: what exactly you want, if you want to load url in web view you can do it web view.loadurl method

Comment: I want to load an url on each webview from  games , movies , top rated
each different pages

Comment: To load url simply use **loadUrl**. More info here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add a WebView in each of your layout (fragment_games.xml, fragment_movies.xml, fragment_top_rated.xml)

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Then in each of the class (GamesFragment, MoviesFragment, TopRatedFragment) define the WebView and load the desired URL. Here i'm doing this for GamesFragment,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.loadUrl("your_url");

        return rootView;
    }
```